# can't add create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm adding create action to food_comment controller for saving comment but there is a no method error on browser.

↓Food_comments controller ↓

```
class FoodCommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @food_comment = current_user.food_comments.build(food_comment_params)
    if @food_comment.save
      redirect_to "/food/#{@food_comment.food.id}"
    end
  end

  private
  def food_comment_params
    params.require(:food).permit(:food_comment).merge(food_id: params[:food_id])
  end
end
```

show view

```
  <div class="container">
      <%= form_with(model: [@food_comment,@food], url:food_food_comments_path(@food), method: :post, local: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :food_comment, placeholder: "add comment", class:"comment_field food_comment_field" %>
      <div><%= f.submit "send", class:"food_comment_btn" %></div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

food model

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :food_image
  has_many :food_comments
  
  with_options presence: true do
    validates :food_title
    validates :food_text
  end
end
```

user model

```
         has_many :cat_posts, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :cat_post_comments, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :foods, dependent: :destroy
         has_many :food_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

[The error pic on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49X1P.png)

I tried to change method but everything I did was wrong and there were same error.
That would be great if someone know how to fix it. I'm looking forward to get some responses, thank you.

it's bit different the error messages after fix user model and food association.

[image: the next error messages]

route

```
  resources :foods do 
    resources :food_comments, only: :create
  end
```

console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.2)
[1] pry(main)> User.first.food_comments
   (0.8ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  FoodComment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `food_comments`.* FROM `food_comments` WHERE `food_comments`.`user_id` = 1
=> []
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the association food_comments is not defined on the user model, Can you please share the code on the `User` model?

Comment: so sorry, I haven't notice that I got a response and you are right I didn't define association to user model and fix it but there is same error message on browser...

Comment: Are you able access the food_comments from rails console, like `User.first.food_comments`?

Comment: Where is your `new` action? How are you getting to the `create` action without a new action? Also your route is named a little funny: `food_food_comments_path` - perhaps rename it.

Comment: consider nesting your routes? pls add your routes file - someone will be able to ehlp

Comment: user11350486, thank you for your reply.
I added console result, I'm not sure that is you expected or not...

Comment: From the screenshot you attached now, It seems there is a typo in the create action. The association name is `food_comments` not `food_comment`, please try correcting and check.

Comment: I changed the name to food_comments in the create action and the error messages was changed!
but it says no route matches even though I defined :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with the path you have redirected on the create action, Try the below (Assuming that you are redirecting to food show page):

```
  def create
    @food_comment = current_user.food_comments.build(food_comment_params)
    if @food_comment.save
      redirect_to food_path(@food_comment.food_id)
    end
  end
```

Also please consider refactoring your controller like the below:

```
class FoodCommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_food

  def create
    @food_comment = @food.food_comments.build(food_comment_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
    if @food_comment.save
      redirect_to food_path(params[:food_id])
    else
      # Handle failure as well
    end
  end

  private
  def set_food
    @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
  end

  def food_comment_params
    params.require(:food).permit(:food_comment)
  end
end
```